# Colocar Fecha Actual en un datetimepicker al Inicializar un Formulario

Tags: c#

Los pongo en contexto. lo que quiero hacer es que al abrir un formulario hijo ya me aparezca la fecha actual en un Datetimepicker... ya que con ello hago una consulta a la base de datos para ver los pendientes del día. 
Por ahora, lo que hago es declarar una variable de tipo Datetime y mandarcela al método para mostrar la consulta, pero al pasarle esa variable a mi Datetimepicker no le pasa nada… y me marca error… 
el error que me marca es el siguiente:

> 'No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.'

Me sale ya que no lleva ningun dato, como que la variable que declare no le paso los datos al datetimepicker...
Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
public partial class Polizacancelada : Form
{
    public Polizacancelada()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        InitializeComponent();
        Pendientes(date);
        fechadependientes.Text = Convert.ToString(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}
```

Avances y Pruebas:

```
public Polizacancelada()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        InitializeComponent();
        Pendientes(date);

        fechadependientes.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        //Le indicas tu formato
        fechadependientes.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        //Aqui bastara pasar el date a ToString()
        fechadependientes.Text = date.ToString();
    }
```

Al hacerlo de esta otra manera:

```
public Polizacancelada()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        InitializeComponent();
        Pendientes(date);

        fechadependientes.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me sale el mismo error con las dos formas...

El metodo al que le mando el Datetime es el siguiente:

```
private void Pendientes(DateTime df)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from CANCELACIONES where Listo='PEN' and FechadeIngreso='"+df.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"'", MenuInicio.conexion);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DA.Fill(DT);
            mostrarpendientes.DataSource = DT;
            if(mostrarpendientes.Rows.Count==0)
            {
                CancelarPendientes.Visible = false;
                mostrarpendientes.Visible = false;
                label5.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CancelarPendientes.Visible = true;
                label5.Visible = false;
                this.mostrarpendientes.Columns["NumCancelacion"].Visible = false;
                this.mostrarpendientes.Columns["NumPoliza"].Visible = false;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mostrarpendientes.Rows)
                {
                    String Dato= row.Cells["Listo"].Value.ToString();
                    if (Dato=="OK")
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
                mostrarpendientes.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por cierto, estás haciendo una doble conversión a string, no tiene nada de malo en sí, pero es innecesario. Puedes borrar el Convert.ToString().

Comment: El error te lo devuelve tu método Pendientes, que no estamos viendo que es lo que debe recibir.

Comment: Puedes colocar la funcion Pendientes(fecha)?

Comment: el metodo que recibe en DateTime esta al final es este:
private void Pendientes(DateTime df)

Comment: has lo siguiente, en visual studio esta la ventana configuracion de excepciones, marca la casilla sobre la excepcion que arroja y ahi te mostrara en que linea exacta te da el error y podras debugear para ver el problema.

Comment: Me parece que el error esta en la consulta a sql, proba hacerla asi = SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from CANCELACIONES where Listo='PEN' and FechadeIngreso='"+df.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'", MenuInicio.conexion);

Comment: ya intente eso y tampoco...

Comment: No se si le estoy asignando la fecha en el lugar incorrecto o que... por que no le asigna ningun formato ni nada... sin enbargo si yo se lo coloco a un Lbel... este si agarra la fecha.

Answer (score 4):

Si deseas poner formato el dateTimePicker puedes utilizar la propiedad Format del picker, y indicarle que lo quieres personalizar

```
 InitializeComponent();
 //Le dices que tome tu formato
 dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
 //Le indicas tu formato
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 Pendientes(date);
 //Aqui bastara pasar el date a ToString()
 dateTimePicker1.Text = date.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Asi de sencillo:

```
  dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: De esta forma no toma el formato mencionado.

Comment: private void fechadependientes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pendientes(Convert.ToDateTime(fechadependientes.Text.ToString()));
        }


--En mi ValueChanged me sale este error si lo pongo de esa manera...

No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.'

por cierto, se que es asi de sencillo... y eso me resulta cuando presiono un boton, pero aqui lo que quiero hacer es que sea al iniciar el formulario sin precionar nada.

Comment: Pendientes(Convert.ToDateTime(fechadependientes.Text.ToString()));  me parece que puede estar aqui el error. pero puedes editar tu pregunta y mostrar la salida de pantalla para ver bien el error y la posicion

Answer (score 0):

La linea siguiente, en el código `private void Pendientes(DateTime df)`parece tener un error:

```
SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from CANCELACIONES where Listo='PEN' and FechadeIngreso='"+df.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"'", MenuInicio.conexion);
```

La conversión parece estar indicada de manera incorrecta:

```
df.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Pienso que deberia ser

```
df.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Quedando la linea completa de la siguiente forma.

```
  SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from CANCELACIONES where Listo='PEN' and FechadeIngreso='"+df.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")+"'", MenuInicio.conexion);
```

No soy entendido en Sql pero pienso que ahí puede haber un error, prueba con este cambio y si resulta me notificas.

---

REVISANDO LA RESPUESTA ANTERIOR.

Revisando con mas detalle tu captura de pantalla, es evidente que tu error es lanzado antes del punto en que te señale la corrección anterior, cuando al llamar al procedimiento `Pendientes` y al pasarle como parámetro la conversión que realizas `Conver.ToDateTime(fechadependientes.Text.ToString())`. Hay aquí varias conversiones que me parecen innecesarias, `fechadependientes.Text` es un `string` por tanto la conversión `fechadependientes.Text.ToString()` no es necesaria, pero además el argumento del procedimiento `Pendientes` es de tipo `DateTime` si `fechadependientes` es el control `DateTimePicker` no es necesario hacer referencia a la propiedad `fechadependientes.Text`, pues el control `DateTimePicker` da como salida la propiedad Value que es de tipo `DateTime`, no es necesario obtener un string para entonces convertirlo a `DateTime` si ya en el `DateTimePicker` tienes ese valor sin necesidad de convertirlo, bastaria con hacer la llamada de la siguiente forma.

```
private void fechadependientes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pendientes(fechadependientes.Value);
}
```

Estos aspectos que te señalo son cosas elementales, no tienen discusión; solo que en tu pregunta hay un error de redacción que viola los requisitos adoptados como practica en este sitio y es que las cuestiones de error en código, no deben mostrarse en imágenes, si no en código escrito (en texto), todos los que han respondido a tú pregunta se han centrado en el código que colocaste, sin embrago el error es lanzado en un procedimiento de tu código que solo aparece en la captura de pantalla.
Te recomiendo hacer el cambio que te indiqué, `Pendientes(fechadependientes.Value);` pero no pierdas de vista, lo que te había dicho anteriormente, pues cuando resuelvas ese error es posible que te salte error en el procedimiento `Pendientes`

Comment: No funciono, sigo intentando otros metodos... pero no logro hacer lo que realmente quiero que haga el sistema

Comment: @JesusDanielVazquezLorenzo Edité mi repuesta, pues se trata de que el error en tu código es anterior al punto en que te señalé, pues revisando tu captura de pantalla, es que me doy cuante, que el error es lanzado en un procedimiento de tu código que solo aparece en la captura de pantalla. las cosas que señalo en la rectificación actual, son cosas elementales, deben funcionar, te recomiendo que lo pruebes y si te funciona, agradecería que marcaras como correcta y puntearas, mi respuesta, soy nuevo en el sitio y me seria de estimulo recibir tu puntuación.